# No package 'libxml++-2.6' found

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to install something using `./configure` but during the process I get this error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libxml++-2.6 >= 2.20) were not met:

No package 'libxml++-2.6' found
```

I already have tried these two commands but no success:

```
$sudo apt-get install libxml2
$sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# apt-get update
# apt-cache search libxml++
......
libxml++2.6-2v5 - C++ interface to the GNOME XML library (libxml2)
libxml++2.6-dev - C++ interface to the GNOME XML library (libxml2) - dev files

# apt-get install libxml++2.6-2v5 libxml++2.6-dev
```